# Debugging with arbitrary NodeJS unit testing frameworks in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, debugging, webstorm, tap

I have forked a NodeJS project that uses the Test Anything Protocol (node-tap). I am using the WebStorm 8.0.1 IDE. I would now like to do step debugging when running the unit tests. Since tap seems pretty obscure in the world of Node, of course there's no run/debug configuration for that framework built into WebStorm.

I was able to run the tests through the IDE by configuring a Node.js run configuration with these settings:

```
Node interpreter: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Node parameters: --debug-brk
Working directory: {my project directory}
JavaScript file: node_modules\tap\bin\tap.js
Application parameters: test/test-*.js
```

However, when debugging with this configuration, my breakpoints are not hit. Additionally, even inserting a `debugger;` statement does not trigger a break.

Is there a way for me to specifically run tap tests in WebStorm? If not, why do you suppose the breakpoints in my tests are not being hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In digging through the `tap` module, it appears that all it does is launch each test file in a child process that runs node; it then just consumes its output which conforms to the Test Anywhere Protocol.

So for me to debug, I can just debug running my test JS directly with Node. This seems to work fine. Hopefully this will help anyone else unfamiliar with this test framework.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using tap over something like [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) or [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)? I know jasmine has lots of support in WebStorm.

Comment: This is a fork from another repository, so I didn't choose the framework. I just wanted to write my changes for a pull request, complete with tests. I definitely prefer mocha over what I've seen in tap so far, though I suppose having TAP output is good for cross-language development.